# Exceptions while using BinaryFormatter to deserialize my serialized data

Tags: c#, serialization, memorystream, binaryformatter

I am using the `BinaryFormatter` and a `MemoryStream` to serialize an object and then store it in a database as a binary blob.  I then retrieve the data from the database and deserialize using binaryformatter and memory stream.

However, when I attempt to deserialize the object I often get exceptions being thrown.  Most notably `'an object with the same key already exists'` or `'cannot convert string to int64'`

Does anyone have an idea as to why the deserialize craps out?  or how to find out what dictionary object is having troubles?

My serialize functions follow...

```
private byte[] SerializeUserData(UserData ud)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(ms, ud);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return data;
}

private UserData Deserialize()
{
    UserData ud = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mSession.BinarySession))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        ud = bf.Deserialize(ms) as UserData;
    }
    return ud; 
}
```

The UserData class is a bit of a monster, but it is marked as [serializable] and all classes in its object tree are also marked as [serializable].  Part of this class follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserData
{
        public UserData() { Clear(); }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public List<Account> OldAccounts{ get; set; }

        public void Clear()
        {
          Account = null;
          OldAccounts = new List<Account>();
          Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
}
```

Comment: Does the `UserData` class implement the `ISerializable` interface?

Comment: Can you provide some details aboute the UserData type?

Comment: Was it serialized and deserialized with exactly the same version of your object dll? By the way, I strongly advise against using BF on a db; something contract-based and platform independent  like protobuf being preferred. BF will hurt you eventually

Comment: Looking at that sample I think we need Account to repro... Essentially well need to repro it to really answer.

Comment: Also, are you sure you've read the entire BLOB from the DB? It is easy to accidentally only read the first chunk.

Comment: There have been compiles between serialization attempts, but no changes to the classes being serialized.  Can you elaborate on your concerns about using BF on a db?

Comment: @yamspog BF is **notoriously** brittle when changing private implementation details, an it is useless between platforms. And it is bigger output and slower than protobuf. Also, a database is about data. BF ist about data; it serialised *implementation* details; type names, field names, etc.

Comment: Respectfully, DataContract style serialization (including protobuff when I last checked) really isn't up to snuff when it comes to usability. It has a very high cost of adoption and is remarkably brittle. I think contract based serialization is really great in the principal of compatibility and explicitly communicating concerns...but it's not where it needs to be in terms of usability, and a lot of internal cross boundary application communication still justifies use of BinaryFormatter.

Comment: @yamspog, do ANY of the classes in the tree implement ISerializable? Are you trying to deserialize after the source has been changed/recompiled? If so, you're not going to maintain binary compatibility, unfortunately, and unless you implement ISerializable, there will be no way to deserialize with respect to class structure changes.

Comment: @JeffN825 well, we'll have to disagree there. And having to implement ISerializable to have any faith in it isn't what I call usability... In my experience switching to DCS or protobuf isn't usually much overhead *at all*.

Comment: I'll agree the usability of BF isn't so hot either...but in personal experience, migrating from .NET remoting to WCF (a WinForms based app communicating with an App Server), we were left with no alternative but to use an IDataContractSerializationSurrogate which under the hood uses the NetDataContractSerializer which under the hood uses the BF, simply because there was no way of preserving LLBLGen entity graphs correctly with any variant of Data Contract style serialization (including protobuf). I've had a bunch of other similar scenarios in the past few years.

Comment: Misspoke, no IDataContractSerializationSurrogate involved actually. Just the NetDCS and BF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried this in recent versions of the framework, but I think the rule of thumb is probably still good, don't use the BinaryFormatter with automatic properties.

The problem is, the BinaryFormatter uses the backing fields and not the properties for doing serialization/ deserialization. In the case of auto properties, the backing field is generated at compile time. And it is not guaranteed to be the same each time. This could mean that you deserialize your object and you don't get back exactly what you put in.

For more read this: [Automatic Properties and the BinaryFormatter](http://blogs.infragistics.com/blogs/josh_smith/archive/2008/02/05/automatic-properties-and-the-binaryformatter.aspx)